# How to use a contract's mapping in test script?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, testing, unittesting, test

Suppose there is a mapping `mapping (address => bool) submitted`.
If want to save something (*like submitted[address] = true*) in this mapping **from test script** while testing how can I do it??

Answer (score 0):

```
    function setUserSubmitStatus(address _user,bool _status) public onlyOwner{
        submitted[_user] = _status;
    }
```

- Create a function to set it in solidity and call to that function.